# can not able to see ads logcat message "Invalid response code: 404"

Tags: android, google-app-engine, admob

I am trying to use admob to show ads on my android app. I am using Google `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.0.4.jar` **SDK** to show ads. i am not able to see ads on my app and i am getting these lines in logcat. i searched on internet but could not able to get any solution. if somebody can help me that will be very grateful for me.

LOGCAT MESSAGE:-

```
04-11 18:10:18.274: INFO/Ads(376): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":15,"u_sd":1.0,"u_w":320,"slotname":"a14da2f44bee388","simulator":1,"msid":"com.google.ads.example","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"4.0.4.android.com.google.ads.example","hl":"en","u_h":480,"testing":1,"u_so":"p","u_audio":4});</script></head><body></body></html>


04-11 18:10:19.384: INFO/Ads(376): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=15&u_sd=1&u_w=320&slotname=a14da2f44bee388&msid=com.google.ads.example&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&format=320x50_mb&net=ed&app_name=4.0.4.android.com.google.ads.example&hl=en&u_h=480&u_so=p&u_audio=4&adtest=on&test_action=overlay&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-330&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=0", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">


04-11 18:10:19.584: INFO/Ads(376): **Invalid response code: 404**


04-11 18:10:19.584: INFO/Ads(376): **onFailedToReceiveAd(There was an internal error.)**
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the Internet permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes i did this as well as i have taken ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission, but i am still getting this message.

Comment: If you go to the browser in the emulator, is it able to open http://www.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got ads in my app. The problem was not with my app but ads were blocked in my office.After enabling ads it is working fine now